# How to put GlassFish online?

Tags: java, glassfish, application-server, portforwarding

I'm trying make GlassFish accessible online, but didn't had any success with it. I disabled Windows firewall, just to be sure it doesn't bother anything. I've set up `<network-listeners>` in `domain.xml` the following way:

```
<network-listeners>
    <network-listener port="8080" protocol="http-listener-1" address="-IPcomeshere" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
    <network-listener port="8181" protocol="http-listener-2" address="-IPcomeshere" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
    <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" address="-IPcomeshere" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
</network-listeners>
```

I've tried the above with a bunch of ports, but no success. I have a D-link DIR-655 router, I set up the virtual servers list this way:

[image: Virtual Servers List]

With this configuration I get the following exception:

> java.net.BindException: No free port within range: 8181=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSSLSelectorHandler@334e9cde
>   SEVERE: Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : No free port within range: 8080=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@29bb22a0

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried adding tcp ports 8080, 8081, 4848 to windows firewall. See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784523%28WS.10%29.aspx) on how to!

Comment: @Jomoos Yes, if I try to start the server, windows firewall prompts me to Allow or Deny the connection, and I set it to allow under all circumstances. Also as I said I've been trying with Windows firewall disabled .

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should try `Port Forwarding`. not `virtual server`.

Basicly it will open those port on you router and redirect the packet send to those ports into your local machine server's port.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP seems unprobable, maybe local one? http://www.whatismyip.com/ gives your IP.

Comment: I entered my actual IP in the config file, I just didn't want to post it here.

Comment: Sorry, should have considered that as minimal intelligence, isn't it. **I leave the answer to someone with more experience on this.**